# Как разместить сокет и express app на одном сервере в одном файле?

Tags: node.js, сервер

У меня в index js есть серверная логика пост, гет, делит запросов и сокет, который отвечает за чат. При запуске на веб сервере он пишет web application can not be started, и причина: events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event. Что мне нужно прописать или изменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `socketio` можно привязать работу к серверу при создании его создании.
Приведу пример создания связки из `express` и `socket.io`.

Я создал промежуточный сервер, который соединяет в себе и `express` и `socketio`. Чтобы это сделать я воспользовался встроенным пакетом - `http` или `https`

### Файл - `@/plugins/express.ts`

```
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import routes from '@/routes';

const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080;

export const app = express();
export const server = createServer(app);

app.use(routes);

export default () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        server.listen(port, () => {
            logger.info(`Сервер запущен на порту: ${port}`);
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
};
```

### Файл - `@/plugins/socket.ts`

```
import { Server as CreateSocketServer } from 'socket.io';
import { server } from './express';
import routes from '@/socket';

export const socket_client = new CreateSocketServer(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: '*',
    },
    cookie: true,
    path: '/client',
});

export default () => {
    routes();
};
```

### Файл - `@/app.ts`

```
import express from './plugins/express';
import socket from './plugins/socket';

(async () => {
    try {
        await express();
        await socket();
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Так это же не решает проблему 2х потоков, сервр не может их обработать, единственное решение, переписать с ws на long pooling или что то подобное

Comment: @NotHacker не совсем понял ваш коммнетарий, я вырвал из своего проекта этот код, который отлично работал как на подключение к сокетам, так и Rest API